# I need to compress the thumb images | PHP

Tags: php, image, file-upload, gd, image-compression

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I have successfully been able to compress the main uploaded image, but I don't know how to use the same function to compress the thumbnail.

The code main purpose is as follows:

1- Upload an image

2- Rename

3- Compress

4- Create thumbnail

5- Compress the thumbnail

My issue it with number 5, I don't know how to compress the thumbnail.

Below are my php and HTML code:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (is_array($_FILES)) {
        if ($_FILES['image']['size'] <= 5000000) {
            $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

            $sourceProperties = getimagesize($file);
            $fileNewName = "[" . "999" . "]-" . time();
            $folderPath = "uploads/";
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $imageType = $sourceProperties[2];


            $data = getimagesize($file);
            $width = $data[0];
            $height = $data[1];

            switch ($imageType) {

                case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                    $imageResourceId = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                    $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId, $sourceProperties[0], $sourceProperties[1]);
                    imagepng($targetLayer, $folderPath . $fileNewName . "_thump." . $ext);
                    break;

                case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                    $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                    $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId, $sourceProperties[0], $sourceProperties[1]);
                    imagegif($targetLayer, $folderPath . $fileNewName . "_thump." . $ext);
                    break;

                case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                    $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                    $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId, $sourceProperties[0], $sourceProperties[1]);
                    imagejpeg($targetLayer, $folderPath . $fileNewName . "_thump." . $ext);
                    break;

                default:
                    echo "Invalid Image type.";
                    exit;
                    break;
            }

            compressImage($file, $folderPath . $fileNewName . "." . $ext, 60);

            echo "Image Resize Successfully.";
        } else {
            echo "too big!";
        }
    }
}

// Compress image
function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality)
{

    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
}


function imageResize($imageResourceId, $width, $height)
{

    $targetWidth = (20 / 100) * $width;

    $targetHeight = (20 / 100) * $height;

    echo $targetWidth . " x " . $targetHeight . " <br> ($width x $height)";

    $targetLayer = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer, $imageResourceId, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $width, $height);

    return $targetLayer;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <a href="index-2.php">Reload Page</a>
```

Please forgive my silly question as I believe it is a very simple question, but I just started developing using php, just few months ago.

Thank you in advance and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The same way you did with the Full size image

Comment: I know same way, I just don't know how, the main image is compressed and uploaded by ```compressImage($file, $folderPath . $fileNewName . "." . $ext, 60);``` I can't figure out how to use the same function with the one that creates the thumbnail.

Comment: Well as the function you wrote just reduces the quality, you could do that on each of the `imageCreateFromXXX` calls in your case statement

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an [`XY-Problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); Because all you are doing is chaging the quality.

If you need low quality thumbnail-image, then set that setting directly while creating thumbnail-image, there is no need to create yet another file.

But if you insist on going on, then simply replace original thumbnail-image with the one created by `compressImage` function, like:

```
$newFilePath = $folderPath . $fileNewName . "." . $ext;
compressImage($file, $newFilePath, 60);

// Replace.
unlink($file); 
rename($newFilePath, $file);
```